# How to fetch all data from doctrine database in DefaultController and then that data forward to a twig template in Symfony4

Tags: doctrine

I'm new to Symfony4 framework and I don't know how to get data from Doctrine database sent to controller and then render it to twig template

```
class DefaultController
{

    private $twig;
    public function __construct(AuthorRepository $authorRepository, EntityFactory $entityFactory, Environment $twig, SerializerInterface $serializer )
    {
        $this->repository = $authorRepository;
        $this->factory = $entityFactory;
        $this->twig = $twig;
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage", methods={"GET"})
     *
     */
    public function homepageAction(): Response
    {
        $body1 = $this->twig->render('layouts/homepage.html.twig');
        print_r($body1);
        die;
    }
```

Comment: Updated text for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller must return `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` object, if you want to use twig template extends your controller class with `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController` and use `render` method.

```
class DefaultController extends AbstractController 
{

/** @var AuthorRepository **/
private $repository;

public function __construct(AuthorRepository $authorRepository)
{
    $this->repository = $authorRepository;
}

/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage", methods={"GET"})
 *
 */
public function homepageAction(): Response
{
    $authors = $this->repository->findAll();
    return $this->render('layouts/homepage.html.twig', ['authors'=>authors]);
}
```

For more informations https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html